# How to use components of one script into another?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to use components (variable, function, objects) of one UnityScript into another. To do so I use following script code, but it throws an exception called `nullpointerreference` and is not displaying value in log.

```
public var hitCar:camrot;

function Update()
{
    if(hitCar.hit==1)
        Debug.Log(hitCar.hit);
}
```

`camrot` is another UnityScript where `hit` variable is declared as `public integer`, and above code is implemented in different script than camrot UnityScript file.

Comment: Any updates here? Did either of the answers get you closer to a solution? Did you find an answer yourself that addresses your problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access variables from another script, you may have to find the GameObject that the script is attached to in order to use it.

(C#, I don't know JavaScript)

Script 1 - Attached to "Player" GameObject, script is called PlayerScript

```
public bool canJump;

void Update()
{
    //code
}
```

Script 2 - Attached to a different GameObject

```
GameObject player;
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.Find("Player"); //finds the gameobject called "Player"
}
void Update()
{
    player.GetComponent<PlayerScript>().canJump = false; //use the variable in another script!
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: sorry but it's not working even when I tried to convert it in javascript

Comment: I used what you suggested but after converting it into javascript

Answer (score 0):

depending on the scope you are looking for just remember if you don't declare a variable and simply assign a value it will automatically be of the GLOBAL scope.

So simply assigning hitCar.hit=1 without declaring it will assign a GLOBAL scope and will work across all interrelated scripts and functions. If you assigned the hitCar.hit in another script then redeclare it in this script it will also revert back to null as well. So remove all declarations and see what happens.

If UNITY is "strict" then declare these variables at the top of the first script file to be executed.